# Colloquial catchy statements encoding serious mathematics

Tags: soft-question, intuition, big-list

As the title says, please share colloquial statements that encode (in a non-rigorous way, of course) some nontrivial mathematical fact (or heuristic).  Instead of giving examples here I added them as answers so they may be voted up and down with the rest.

This is a community-wiki question: One colloquial statement and its mathematical meaning per answer please!

Comment: Recent answers suggest this question is getting a bit long in the tooth.

Answer (score 122):

> A drunk man will find his way home, but a drunk bird may get lost forever.

This encodes the fact that a 2-dimensional [random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) is recurrent (appropriately defined for either the discrete or continuous case) whereas in higher dimensions random walks are not.  More details can be found for instance in [this enjoyable blog post](http://godplaysdice.blogspot.com/2007/09/variations-on-drunken-bird-theorem-and.html) by Michael Lugo.

Comment: This particular saying, by the way, is usually attributed to Shizuo Kakutani.  (I don't want anybody thinking I came up with it!)

Comment: And this is the reason that birds do not drink alcohol

Comment: I feel it should be a drunk spaceship, since birds fly at most over a thickened 2-sphere, and realistically over just a small patch.

Answer (score 79):

> "Can you hear the shape of a drum?"

This was [Kac's famous way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum) of asking whether the shape of a two-dimensional domain could be reconstructed from the spectrum of the Laplacian on that domain.  (The answer, by the way, is "no", at least if one allows the domain to have corners.)

Answer (score 79):

An anagram for "Banach Tarski" is "Banach Tarski Banach Tarski"

Comment: I don't think this is what Armin Straub was looking for, but it certainly made me laugh. ^_^

Comment: I'd like to know the original source of this. I put it on a T-shirt. http://thenerdiestshirts.com/site/math-t-shirts-banach-tarski

Comment: Well, anyway it should be Hausdorff.

Comment: If only King Solomon had known about the Banach-Tarski paradox.  Instead of cutting the baby into two pieces, he could have suggested 5 pieces and made *both* mothers happy.

Answer (score 65):

> Take a map of wherever you are and lay it on the ground. There will be exactly one point on the map that is directly above the point it represents on the ground.

This refers to Banach's fixed point theorem.

Comment: This should also follow from Brouwer's fixed-point theorem, right? If so, it's the best statement of Brouwer's fixed-point theorem I've ever heard, and I'll definitely be using it in the future!

Comment: You need Banach's fixed point for the uniqueness, but the existence follows Brouwer's fixed point.

Comment: i actually did this in class to demonstrate the fixed point theorem. there was a satisfying gasp when I picked up my lecture notes and scrunched them :)

Comment: With this formulation one may say that even the proof somewhat made its way thorugh and reached literature. In Borges "Partial Enchantments of the Quixote" a story contained in Other Inquisitions, an apocryphal quote states that in a perfect map, a copy of the map should be contained, and such copy would contain another copy of the map and so on at infinity, which is basically the proof of the Theorem, if you add to it existence of the limit...

Answer (score 51):

> Complete disorder is impossible.

This is the standard way of summing up [Ramsey theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory) in a succinct sentence (according to that Wikipedia article, the above quote is due to Motzkin).

Comment: By the way, Motzkin's remark, which is in a paper in J. Comb. Theory 3:244-252 (1967) made an interesting comparison between disorder in physics and combinatorics: "Whereas the entropy theorems of probability and mathematical physics imply that, in a large universe, disorder is probable, certain combinatorial theorems imply that complete disorder is impossible."

Answer (score 49):

> It's not possible to comb a hedgehog.

Or, alternatively:

> You can't comb the hair on a coconut.

Both statements are referring to the fact that every continuous tangent vector field on the 2-sphere has to vanish at some point. That's the well known [Hairy ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

Comment: Armin, you obviously travel in more poetic circles than I!  I'd always just heard “you can't comb a hairy ball”.

Comment: Of course one can comb a hedgehog, but not without a bald point! 

Comment: Those who comb hedgehogs for a living know that they have bald bellies: http://goo.gl/E1HWh

Answer (score 48):

**"Space tells matter how to move; matter tells space how to curve."**

This is the quintessential colloquial expression of the [Einstein field equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) that govern general relativity.

Comment: Good  one\!!!!!!

Comment: Punchy as that is, I regret that it was not bequeathed to us in the form "Space tells matter where to go; matter tells space to get bent."

Answer (score 45):

> "The shortest path between two truths in the real domain passes through the complex domain."
>   -- Jacques Hadamard

I guess he meant that often the best proof of a theorem about real numbers uses complex analysis.

Comment: No, he meant something even better.  A real integral is often best found by a path through the complex plane.

Answer (score 40):

> All primes are odd except 2, which is the oddest of all.

This [has been discussed before](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/915/is-there-a-high-concept-explanation-for-why-characteristic-2-is-special). The quote is from "Concrete Mathematics," but it's a rephrasal of one of J.H. Conway in "The book of numbers."

Comment: _Concrete Mathematics_ (1989, 2nd ed. 1994) was published before _The book of numbers_ (1996).

Comment: I heard it from John Thompson in 1960. As well as an other inadvertent quote of his when he was speaking to an audience at a catholic school about variants of the Cantor set--" there's nothing sacred about the number 3".

Answer (score 39):

"A projective module is the splittin' image of a free module."

Comment: Ha ha :) made me laugh, or at least grin wryly.

Comment: Love it! (and love it, to fill out more characters)

Comment: As a non-native english speaker I don't get the joke. Could someone explain please?

Comment: "X is the spitten image of Y" is an informal phrase meaning "X looks just like Y".

"X is the spitting image of Y" is an entirely equivalent phrase; in some dialects, the pronunciation is even the same.

As far as I know, neither is the "right spelling"; the phrase rarely appears in written English.

Comment: @jasomill: Did you intentionally write "spit" instead of "split"? Both "splitten" and "splitting" are correctly spelled words; I don't understand your comment on incorrect spelling.

Comment: I think he's talking about "spitten" (past participle) versus "spitting" (present participle).

Comment: @Rasmus: The English colloquialism uses "spit", so that "split" is a pun. See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8509/.

Comment: It may be that the original is "spit and image".

Comment: @TomGoodwillie, Language Log thinks that the history is the other way 'round:  http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=14592 .

Answer (score 34):

"If you are walking between two policemen going to the same station, you will end up there, too."

This encodes the familiar Squeeze Theorem: If $a_n,b_n, c_n$ are sequences of real numbers such that $a_n \leq b_n \leq c_n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n =\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n =\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n= \lim_{n \to \infty}b_n$.

I am not sure whether it counts as "serious mathematics", but this is how I learned it as a high school student in Communist-ruled Poland.

Comment: In France it is called the "policemen theorem" too.

Comment: I learned it in an Israeli high school from a Russian teacher and he called it two policemen and a drunk. So the drunk is between the two policmen who are going to the station.

Comment: And then there is the running joke of calling it the "three policemen" theorem because the drunk is a policeman as well.

Comment: In Italy too (or rather the "Carabinieri" theorem, soldiers of a police force commonly regarded as ridiculous)

Comment: No one calls it the Sandwich Theorem?

Comment: I did learn it as a sandwich theorem. But the policemen gag is better!

Comment: Of course, in most practical applications one policeman is 0 and the other tends to 0.

Answer (score 32):

"If it walks like a sphere and it quacks like a sphere then it is a sphere."

A professor at my university explained the Poincare Conjecture to his 1st semester abstract algebra students this way. I think it is a great explanation!

Answer (score 31):

> There is a pair of antipodal points on the surface of the Earth at equal temperature and equal pressure.

The [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) for n=2. Suppose $f: \mathbb{S}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous map. Then $\exists x: f(x) = f(-x)$.

Comment: While the pressure field should  be continuous, I can see no reason why the temperature field have to be continuous?


Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Indeed, [near-zero-Kelvin](http://www.dwavesys.com/d-wave-two-system) labs on Earth mean it's probably not.

Answer (score 31):

If n people are in an elevator and n+1 buttons are pushed, there is at least one pigeon brain in the elevator.

Comment: Who you calling pigeon brain? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDntbGRPeEU  :-)

Comment: "If there are fewer pigeons than holes, there must be a pigeon with at least two holes in it."

Answer (score 30):

> Period three implies chaos.

This summarizes a paper (of the same name) by Li and Yorke. The full statement of the main theorem is that if a continuous transformation of an interval has a point whose orbit has length three, then there exist points whose orbits are completely chaotic (in addition to points with orbits of every other possible finite length).

Comment: One should read the interchange between Li, Yorke and Ruelle that took place in the AMS Notices about this!

Comment: Mariano, do you happen to remember where or when that took place?

Comment: @L Spice: http://www.ams.org/notices/200906/rtx090600688p.pdf and http://www.ams.org/notices/200910/rtx091001232p.pdf

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko, somehow I didn't see this comment until 7/2 years later.  Thanks, belatedly!

Answer (score 29):

Two plus two is four. You can prove that two plus two is four.  You can *prove* that you can prove that two plus two is four.  And you can prove that you can prove that you can prove that two plus two is four, and so on.

Two plus two is not five. You can prove that two plus two is not five. You can't prove that two plus two *is* five, or else math is a lot of bunk. But, if math is not a lot of bunk, you *can't prove* that you can't prove that two plus two is five.

(Shortened from [Gödel's Second Incompleteness Theorem Explained in Words of One Syllable](http://www2.kenyon.edu/Depts/Math/Milnikel/boolos-godel.pdf)
 by George Boolos, *Mind*, Vol. 103, January 1994, pp. 1 - 3.)

Answer (score 27):

> A brain tangled enough to tackle
>   itself must be too tangled to tackle.

A neat formulation of Goedel's Incompleteness Theorem.
From the novel  "Galatea 2.2" by R.Powers.

Comment: Well, it takes two to tangle.

Answer (score 23):

> Odd is better, but three is best.

This refers to the fact that "sound" propagation in arbitrary dimensions (using the wave equation on an initial pulse) is only possible in odd-dimensional spaces (in even dimensions there's an ever-lasting echo), and that dispersion-free propagation only happens for dimension three.

See this paper where I saw the quote: [part one](http://www.physics.iitm.ac.in/~labs/dynamical/pedagogy/vb/3dpart1.pdf), [part two](http://www.physics.iitm.ac.in/~labs/dynamical/pedagogy/vb/3dpart2.pdf), although the fact itself seems to be known for ages (I have no access but an [old paper](http://www.iop.org/EJ/abstract/0370-1298/68/6/307) by Balazs seems relevant too), possibly this even goes back to Petrovskii according to an [interview of Arnold](http://www.ams.org/notices/199704/arnold.pdf) (see p434).

Comment: This is also known as the "strong Huygens principle".

Comment: And one of the better tongue-in-cheek titles of a paper I've seen: "A Simple Proof that the World is Three-Dimensional".

Answer (score 21):

> "Chewy on the outside, crunchy on the inside."

The way that Dick Canary would characterize hyperbolic 3-manifolds with nonempty (and nonrigid) conformal boundary.

> "Crunchy on the outside, chewy on the inside."

Description of Rich Schwartz's complex hyperbolic manifold with conformal boundary a real hyperbolic manifold.

Answer (score 19):

Fields medalist René Thom famously wrote:

> Ce qui limite le vrai n'est pas le faux, mais l'insignifiant.
>   (Approx translation: "What limits truth is not wrongfulness, it's meaninglessness.")

This refers to the basic mathematical issue that one must only consider [well-formed formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) rather than arbitrary ones.

Comment: Is that really what he meant? That seems like a pretty narrow interpretation. 

Comment: Nice, but I'm not convinced by the translation. Here's my take: "Truth is not bounded by falsity, but by the insignificant", which I imagine means something like: "A true statement is worthless if its scope is very limited." (I'd never heard this statement and have no idea what Thom's intentions were, but being French I can perhaps help point to the way out of meaninglessness)

Answer (score 18):

> Black holes have no hair.

This [no-hair theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_hair_theorem) "postulates that all black hole solutions of the Einstein-Maxwell equations of gravitation and electromagnetism in general relativity can be completely characterized by only three externally observable classical parameters: mass, electric charge, and angular momentum".

Comment: This is of course true only in 4 dimensions.  Higher-dimensional black holes can be hairy.

Answer (score 18):

> After stirring a cup of coffee, at least one point will end up in the
>   exact same position as it was before.

Being an approximate statement of Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

Comment: I've always had issues with this one since I'm not convinced the "stirring" function would be continuous...

Comment: Indeed, if you place the spoon vertically in the middle of the coffee mug down to the bottom, the coffee will cease to be contractible.

Answer (score 18):

> A city is **compact** if it can be patrolled by finitely many nearsighted police officers.

I believe this is due to Peter Lax.  Of course one must take some care with quantifiers to make this a correct definition, but I think it captures the spirit nicely.

Comment: I think this is a dangerous metaphor: it encourages the misconception that "a space is compact iff it has a finite open cover".

Comment: This is attributed to Weyl in Wilson Sutherland's text *Introduction to Metric and Topological Spaces* (section 5.2).  Sutherland gives it as "If a city is compact, it can be guarded by a finite number of arbitrarily near-sighted policemen".  Exercise 5.10.15 asks you to make precise, and discuss the accuracy of, Weyl's statement.

Comment: A city is compact if you can fire all except finite number of policemen patrolling the city

Comment: @TomLeinster The original may well be this, from Weyl’s [*Harmonics on homogeneous manifolds*](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1503175), p. 489: «A “finite” country can be watched by a finite number of policemen, however small the radius of action of the single policeman may be!»

Answer (score 15):

**Time Average is the Space Average**

which is the the Ergodic Theorem.

Comment: It seems like a reasonable way of summarizing it catchily, but I'd prefer a little extra context -- as stated it reads like it could be something from Time Cube...

Answer (score 13):

Trust, but verify.

this is the defn of NP, of course, but for a certain generation, it has Reaganesque overtones.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page on this catchphrase (yes, Wikipedia has a "trust, but verify" page), it originates in a Russian proverb, as Reagan himself introduced it.

Answer (score 12):

All diagrams commute.

The actual theorem is [Mac Lane's Coherence Theorem](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/06/29/mac-lanes-coherence-theorem/) or any of a number of other [coherence theorems](http://www.google.com/search?q=coherence+%22all+diagrams+commute%22) that guarantee that all category diagrams built from certain elements commute.

Answer (score 12):

> Local is global

The very first thing I heard about sheaves, from another graduate student.

Comment: A variant (with different mathematical overtones):  "Think globally, act locally".  I had a button with this on it as an undergraduate, from a very non-mathematical source.

Comment: This reminds me of a Gogol Bordello song... "Think locally ______"

Comment: The same is true for convex optimization....

Answer (score 12):

Another one: not so much a catchphrase, but a nifty interpretation of a theorem:

"Suppose a human is walking a dog on the leash and they encounter a lamp post. Then, if the leash is kept short enough, the human and the dog wind around the post the same number of times."

I learned this interpretation of Rouche's Theorem from the textbook in complex analysis by Saff and Snider. They include pictures, too.

Comment: By “the leash is kept short enough”, do you mean it can't be flung over the lamp?


Answer (score 11):

The consequences of this little harmless looking statement are deep enough that I worry that the majority will think that it is provably wrong.

Simple statement:

- "You can pick a real number at random between 0 and 1, so that any number is as likely as any other."

more colloquially, (Freiling):

- "You can throw a dart at the unit square."

more computer-scienc-y:

- "The process of coin flipping to determine the binary digits of a real number converges to a unique well defined real number answer in the limit of infinitely many throws".

The interpretation of this statement is not that the probability distribution of the result is a well defined function, nor that statements about whether this number is in this or that Borel set can be assigned a probability--- both these assertions are true and boring. The assertion above is that a real number "x" produced in this way actually exists as an element of the mathematical universe, and every question you can ask of it, including "does x belong to this arbitrary subset S of [0,1]" gets a well defined yes or no answer in the limit. If you believe this assertion is self-evidently true, as I do, beware the implications!

- The continuum hypothesis is false. (Sierpinsky,Freiling)

For contradiction, well order [0,1] with order type aleph-1, then choose two numbers x,y at random in [0,1]. What is the probability that $y\le x$ in the well-ordering? Since the set $\{ z|z\le y\} $ is countable for any y, the answer is 0. The same thing works whenever sets of cardinality less than the continuum always have zero Lebesgue measure.

- Every subset of [0,1] has well-defined Lebesgue measure. (Solovay, more or less)

Make a countable list of independent numbers $x_i$, and ask for each one whether the number is in the set S or not. The fraction of random picks which land in S will define the Lebesgue measure of S. In more detail, if you write down a "1" every time $x_i$ is in S, and write down a zero when $x_i$ is not in S, then the number of ones divided by the number of throws converges to a unique real number, which defines the Lebesgue measure of S.

In this forum, somewhere or other, someone had the idea that this process will not converge for sets S which are not measurable, alternating between long strings of "0"s and long strings of "1"s in such a way that it will not have an average frequency of 1's. This is impossible, because the picks are independent. That means that any permutation of the 0's and 1's is as likely as any other. If you have a long string of N zeros and ones, the only permutation invariant of these bits is the number of ones. Any segregation of zeros or ones that has oscillating mean has less than epsilon probability whenever the mean number of ones after M throws, deviates by more than a few times $\sqrt{\ln \epsilon}/\sqrt{N}$ from the mean established by the first N throws.

It is astonishing to me that someone here simultaneously holds in their head the two ideas: "there exists a non measurable subset of [0,1]" and "you can choose a real number at random between [0,1]". The negation of the first statement is the precise statement of the second.

(Solovay defined this stuff precisely, but did not accept the resulting model as true. Others take the axiom of determinacy, thereby establishing that all subsets of R are measurable and that choice fails for the continuum, but determinacy is a stronger statement than "you can pick in [0,1]".)

- The axiom of choice fails, already for sets of size the continuum.

Since the axiom of choice easily gives a non-measurable set.

- The continuum has no well order.

This is because you could then do choice on the reals. So the first bullet on this list should really be rephrased as "the continuum hypothesis is just a stupid question".

- Sorry, you can NOT cut up a grape and rearrange the pieces so that it is bigger than the sun.

Simply because if you put a grape next to the sun, and pick a random point in a big box that surrounds both, the probability that the random point lands in the grape is less than the probability that it lands in the sun. The Lebesgue measure of the pieces is well defined, and invariant under translations and rotations, so it never amounts to more than the measure of the grape.

- The reals which are in "L", the Godel constructable universe, have measure zero.

When the axiom of Choice holds for all elements of the powerset of Z (i.e. R), then the pea can be split up and rearranged to make the sun. The axiom of choice holds in L, so that the Godel constructible L-points in the pea can be cut up and rotated and translated to fit over the L-points of the sun. This means that these points make a measure zero set, both in the pea and in the sun, when considered as a sub-collection of the real numbers which admit random picks.

To understand the Godel constructible universe, and choice, I will pretend that the phrase "Godel constructible" simply means "computable." This is a bald-faced lie. the Godel constructible universe contains many non-computable numbers, but they all resemble computable numbers, in that they are defined by a process which takes an ordinal number of steps and at each step uses only text sentences of ZF acting on previously defined objects. If you replace ordinal by "omega" and "text sentences acting on previously defined elements" by "arithmetical operations defined on previously defined memory", you get computable as opposed to Godel-constructible. To well order the Godel universe, you just order the objects constructed at each ordinal step by alphabetical order and ordinal birthday. To well order the computable reals, you just order their shortest program alphabetically (like the well-ordering of the Godel-universe, this ordering is explicitly definable, but not computable).

- That stupid hat trick doesn't work in the random-pick real numbers

There is a recently popularized puzzle: A demon puts a hat, either red or green, on the head of a countably infinite number of people. Each person sees everyone else's hat, and is told to simultaneously guess the color on their heads. If infinitely many get this wrong, everybody loses. If only finitely many people get the answer wrong, everybody wins.

When the demon picks the hat color randomly on each person's head, they lose. Each person has 50% chance of getting their hat right. End of story. Nothing more to say. Really. This is why set theory has nothing to do with weather prediction.

- The stupid hat trick does work over the computable reals, but is intuitive.

If the demon is forced to place hats according to a fixed definite computer program, there are only countably many different programs, the demon must pick a program, and stick with it. Then it is reasonable that each person can figure out the program used from the infinite answers at their disposal, up to a finite number of errors.

Supposing the people are provided just with some halting oracles and a prearranged agreement regarding computer programs. They do not need a choice function on the continuum. The people see the other hats, and they test the computer programs one by one, in lexicographic order, until they find the shortest program consistent with what they see. They then go through all the programs again, until they find the shortest program on integers which will give be only different from what they see in finitely many places (this requires a stronger oracle, but it still doesn't require a choice function). Then they answer with the value of this program at their own position.

(more precisely, to see everyone else's hat means that the demon provides a program which will give the value of everyone elses hat. You use the halting oracle to test whether each program successively will answer correctly on everyone else's hat, until you find the shortest program that does so.)

This version also has application to weather prediction: by studying the weather long enough, you can guess that it is obeying the Navier Stokes equations. Then you can simulate these equations to predict the weather. Come to think of it, this is exactly what we humans did.

- The stupid hat trick is also intuitive in L, so long as you always think inside a countable model of ZF(C).

The demon again is constrained to definable reals below omega one, which is now secretly a countable ordinal (but ZF doesn't know it). So there is very little difference between the conceptual method to guess the definable real, except that now it isn't so easy to interpret things in terms of oracles.

- There is no problem with "$R_L$, the L version of R, coexisting inside $R_R$, the actual version of R, in your mental model of the universe.

The axiom of choice is true in L, which includes a particular model for the real numbers (and all powersets). This model is fine for interpreting all the counterintuitive statements of ZFC, since they are just plain true in L. When you read a choicy theorem, you just imagine little "L" subscripts on the theorem, and then it is true (this is called relativizing to L in logic). But you always keep in mind that L is measure zero. Then that's it. There are no more intuitive paradoxes.

Your mental axiom system for no-intuitive-paradox mathematics than can be this

ZF (but you interpret powerset as "L-powerset")

V=L (and therefore Choice for all sets in your universe, and the continuum hypothesis for the constructible reals, and for the constructible powersets)

For each set S in the universe L, (which is well-ordered by V=L), there is a non-well-orderable proper class of subsets of S, the true power-class. Every subclass of a powerclass has a real valued Lebesgue measure, and every subset (meaning well-orderable sub-SET, not a non-well-orderable subCLASS) of a powerclass has measure zero. All powerclasses are the same size, since they are not powerclasses of previous powerclasses, just powerclasses of dinky little sets. The measure of the proper-class completion of the dinky little measure-zero L-Borel sets is the same as the measure assigned to these Borel sets in L.

This system does nothing but shuffle the intuition around. There is no new real mathematics here (no new arithmetic theorems). But with this in your head, you banish all the choice paradoxes to the dustbin of history. No more puzzles, no more paradoxes, no more nothing. This has been a public service announcement.

Answer (score 11):

If you save a penny a day, eventually you will become a millionaire. This is a loose paraphrase of the Archimedean Property of Archimedean Ordered Fields:

If $\epsilon \gt 0$ and if $M \gt 0$, then $\exists$ an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\epsilon\gt M$.

Comment: This property has another paraphrase: even taking very small steps one can walk a very long way (known in Polish as "twierdzenie o malych piechurach", i.e, "theorem on little walkers"). Sounds like Comrade Mao... 

Answer (score 11):

> Being compact is the next best thing to being finite.

As seen for example by the fact that the (uniform) limit of a sequence of continuous real-valued functions on a compact space is continuous. Or the even more down to earth example: The extreme value theorem.

Comment: I've heard a minor variation: "Compact is the new finite."

Answer (score 10):

The [ham sandwich theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem) comes to mind: given n measurable sets in **R**<sup>n</sup>, there is a hyperplane (i. e. an affine subspace of codimension 1) that bisects them all.  I don't know of a colloquial way to state this, though.

Comment: You can just say: "a ham sandwich (two pieces of bread and one of ham) can be split in half with a single cut."

Comment: Ricardo, that's true.  But I feel like what's really remarkable is that this holds in all dimensions, and ham sandwich definitely brings to mind a three-dimensional picture.

Comment: So just take an n-dimensional ham sandwich... :)

Comment: @CamMcLeman, "all right, I got a 7-dimensional ham sandwich, a 12-dimensional ham sandwich, and a 57-dimensional ham sandwich."  "Oh, that last one is Grothendieck's."

Answer (score 10):

> I had to walk to school uphill both ways.

I've found that this is one of the better ways to try to explain the idea behind non-commutative geometry to a layperson.

Comment: Sorry. I really don't understand...

Comment: It is not a perfect analogy, but I think that the intuition built from this statement helps to understand something like the Aharanov-Bohm effect in quantum mechanics. In this case, the quantum phase of a particle moving from point A to point B depends on the path taken to get there. So if we wave our hands and replace 'phase' with 'altitude', then we could imagine that there are two different paths from A to B, one which is 'uphill' and one which is 'downhill'. And so you might have a notion of walking uphill to school both ways.

A quick introduction to the Aharanov-Bohm effect and its

Comment: interpretation in terms of noncommutative geometry can be found at http://www.physik.uni-regensburg.de/forschung/krey/papkre0

Comment: I like it as a way to explain cohomology on a closed circuit graph, as an alternative to exactness ⇒ Green's theorem.

Comment: I heard this in a Monty Python sketch. But I don't suppose they were thinking about non-commutative geometries or quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 9):

Surprised this one hasn't appeared yet:

> The flap of a butterfly's wings in
>   Brazil can set a tornado in Texas.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect

Answer (score 8):

A straight line is the shortest distance between two points.

Comment: How can a line be a distance?

Comment: @Rasmus: I was initially uncertain whether to take your question seriously.  But I find some answers to the original question that seem to construe the question in an altogether different way from what appears to me to have been intended.  I thought "colloquial catchy statements" meant things that ordinary non-mathematicians would say, giving words the meanings they normally have in the usages of non-mathematicians.  My answer here is verbatim the way it's normally heard.

Comment: This is entirely subjective, but to me this does not feel like the way it's normally heard. Maybe "the shortest way"?

Comment: Seems to me you're trying to make it fit into the conventions used by mathematicians, not shared by others.

Comment: Enter these four terms into Google: straight line shortest two

Comment: That's possible. The google result shocked me. ;)

Answer (score 8):

I'm surprised that nobody has mentioned the famous,

> "Four colors suffice."

Answer (score 8):

> This sentence is false.

The famous [liar paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox). As the wiki article explains:

> If "this sentence is false" is true,
>   then the sentence is false, which
>   would in turn mean that it is actually
>   true, but this would mean that it is
>   false, and so on ad infinitum.
>
> Similarly, if "this sentence is false"
>   is false, then the sentence is true,
>   which would in turn mean that it is
>   actually false, but this would mean
>   that it is true, and so on ad
>   infinitum.

Alternately,

> All Cretans are liars.

or as pointed out in the comment below the [Barber paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox):

> The barber shaves only those men in
>   town who do not shave themselves.Who
>   shaves the barber?

Comment: Don't forget the (male) barber who shaves only those who do not shave themselves: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox 

This encodes Russell's antinomy.

Answer (score 7):

> Truth is undefinable,

which is a statement of Tarski's theorem.  More precisely,

> Truth in a context where one can do arithmetic is undefinable in that context.

Answer (score 6):

There is no free lunch.
Refers to risk/reward in financial investment and the fact that an efficient market moves to the point where you can only make money by taking risk.

Answer (score 6):

Kronecker was wrong: God did not make the integers. He only made the empty set. Then He made mathematicians so they could make the integers from the empty set.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between the empty set and other sets here.  If mathematicians construct sets from other sets, then they could construct the empty set from other sets as well.  

Comment: Assume there was no empty set.  Consider the set of all empty sets, ... [seen years ago in Martin Gardner; not sure of the original source]

Comment: It is a bit like: Assume there were no proofs by contradiction....

Answer (score 5):

> There is a way to cut up a pea and rearrange the pieces to get the sun.

As a corollary of the Banach-Tarski paradox, we have that if A and B are bounded subsets of R^n (n > 2) with nonempty interior, there exists a partition of A into k pieces {A1, ..., Ak} and isometries of R^n {f1, ... , fk} so {f1A1, ... , fkAk} partitions B.

Comment: This is not an immediate consequence, and the pea-to-sun statement is a highly misleading translation of the statement of the theorem. Both the pea and sun are roughly spherical, but the theorem shows that you can geometrically decompose a sphere into two spheres of the same radius, not into a sphere of a different radius. If you disagree, please tell me how many pieces you will use to go from a ball of radius 1 into a ball of radius 2. I would use 9 pieces to decompose a sphere into two of the same radius, although that's not minimal.

Comment: Maybe it shoud be formulated as: Give me one pea and I'll feed the world. :-)

Comment: @Douglas: There is a generalization of the Banach-Tarski-theorem that applies to almost arbitrary subsets of IR^n. (I think the precise condition is that they have non-empty interior)

Comment: @Johannes: I think that, in addition to having non-empty interior, the sets need to be bounded.

Comment: Visualize world peas?


Comment: How about: there is a way for Jesus to distribute the fish and loaves to feed the multitudes. 

Answer (score 5):

You Can’t Unscramble Scrambled Eggs

Comment: As a statement asserting the existence of one-way functions, P /= NP, or the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: I understand the others, but how does this relate to P vs. NP?

Comment: The existence of one-way functions implies P/=NP, in that for any such function p, its inverse function, hp, would, by definition, be hard to compute for any input, but any output would be easy to verify using p. 

Comment: Ah, but theorem: Consider a compact pan with some unscrambled eggs in a closed (no "external" i.e. time-varying physics) classical Newtonian (energy is kinetic, which is positive-def quadratic in velocity, plus potential, which depends only on position) universe.  The eggs may be in the process of scrambling.  Then at some time in the future (indeed, after some precisely integer number of years, where how long you have to wait can be given an explicit absolute bound in terms of epsilon), the eggs will be within epsilon of unscrambled.

Comment: Non-mathematically, this reminds me of the cryptic crossword clue:

gegs (9,4).

Answer (score 5):

> It's better to be lucky than good.

P != NP. A nondeterministic polynomial is one which is always "lucky".

Comment: Given that `P!=NP` is unproven, perhaps *I hope it's better to be lucky than good*.

Comment: Or "better lucky than smart"

Answer (score 4):

> There's no such thing as a free lunch.

This refers to the No Free Lunch theorem. The theorem states that it's impossible to develop a search optimization algorithm that works well for all possible problems. Rather, for every class of problems which a given algorithm performs well at, there is a complementary class for which it does not. Thus, you may think you're getting a free lunch, but you're really just paying for it somewhere else.

Comment: Duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3559/colloquial-catchy-statements-encoding-serious-mathematics/14112#14112

Comment: Not an exact duplicate. Here its about optimization and not about finance.

Answer (score 4):

I like the phrase ``counting in two different ways'' -- which I learned in a math camp.  If you're not sure what it means, I suggest the exercise of trying to prove that $2^n = \sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i}$ by looking for a proof which could be aptly described by this phrase.

Answer (score 4):

> Non-random is a special case of random.

When studying probability distributions, and start with the dirac delta function.

Answer (score 3):

Even quite irregularly shaped objects, such as tables and chairs, become approximately spherical if you wrap them in enough newspaper.

(I think this is by J. H. Conway but I heard it through Bill Thurston, who we recently lost.  RIP.)

Comment: What is the serious mathematics that this encodes? 

Answer (score 2):

> Adding an axiom saying that something's provable
>   doesn't help you prove it.

A characterization for [Lob's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem) from reddit user [noop_noob](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/fco9zd/whats_the_craziest_or_most_mind_blowing/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

Answer (score 1):

> Poisson arrivals see time averages.

Answer (score 1):

> Nothing contains everything.

or

> There is no universe.

This is how [Halmos](http://books.google.at/books?id=x6cZBQ9qtgoC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) (pp. 6-7) summarizes the answer of axiomatic set theory to Russell's paradox.

Answer (score -3):

GAGA the acronym for Serre's famous *Geometrie algebrique geometrie analytique*.

Answer (score -6):

Numbers are mutually friendly if they share their abundancy