# "You can't push a rope"

Tags: engineering-mathematics, oc.optimization-and-control, soft-question

"You can't push a rope" is a wisdom saying that some engineering teachers pass along to their students.  Since I'm not an engineer, I can only guess at what they mean, but it sounds to me like code for a mathematical principle (but from control theory? numerical analysis? ergodic theory? dynamical systems? statistics?)

1) I would appreciate having any mathematicians who work with engineers hazard a general framework for a rigorous formulation of what the *engineers* mean by this slogan.

2) I would like to know of any deep theorems that (of the no-go variety) that naturally fall under this rubric (whether engineers know about these theorems or not).

Comment: Perhaps you can post it as an answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3559/colloquial-catchy-statements-encoding-serious-mathematics and wait for comments ;)

Comment: When I was an engineering student, I had a professor who said it, and meant it literally.  I remember drawing structure diagrams with arrows representing forces at all the nodes.  A solid beam could have compression and tension forces at either end, but ropes or cables could only have tension.

Comment: Amit Kumar Gupta, that is certainly useful for me to hear!  Of course a solid beam has few significant internal degrees of freedom, so a small state space, and just the opposite for a rope.  So to me the literal interpretation seems paradigmatic for any situation where a long causal chain has small errors that will accumulate and overwhelm the desired effect or signal.  I first heard this decades ago from an MIT student who definitely thought he was getting a broad message, but one he couldn't quite explain to me.

Comment: I have no background in engineering, but I remember saying "You are pushing on a rope," a few times. Rather than something deep, I think these boiled down to  $P \implies Q. ~Q \therefore ~...$

Comment: I remember once pushing a rope when it was on the ground... perhaps the saying has a second part "unless it is on the ground". :-)

Comment: How this should be translated into Russian ? "Вы не можете нажать на веревке" - translate.google.com - does not make sense for me ... 

Comment: @Alexander: Веревку невозможно толкать. 

Comment: Actually, it would be interesting to solve it as a control theory problem. Model a rope as a large number of points connected by short incompressible rods, and suppose that initially they are perfectly aligned and horizontal. Then you can "push the rope" by applying a horizontal force which will be propagated through the rods. But this is an unstable equilibrium; is it possible to determine vertical "control" forces that keep the rope in a neighbourhood of the unstable equilibrium point, while pushing the rope horizontally at the same time?

Comment: @Federico Poloni: You could put the rope in a nearly-frictionless trough with a "V"-shaped cross-section.  (Also, I think most real-life ropes have small but nonzero restoring forces, due to their nonzero cross-section).

Comment: @S. Carnahan: in my comment I meant a rope on an Euclidean plane, without gravity. It is not clear to me whether it is possible or not: for instance, with n=2 points it should be equivalent to the classical "how to balance a rod on your nose" example problem in control theory.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushing_on_a_string

Answer (score 10):

The rigorous mathematical context is stability. A straight rope in either tension or compression is a valid solution of the underlying PDE, but in compression this solution is unstable, so it cannot be realized in practice.

Answer (score 6):

See http://engsci.unavoidable.ca/civ102/CIV102-Notebook.pdf pages 26 and 27 for a mathematical discussion of why you can't push a rope (from a civil engineering course).

Comment: For those like me on somewhat slow connections: that pdf is *large* (ca 70 Mb). 

Answer (score 4):

It's not as mystical as you seem to think.  Simply, for a rope to be an efficacious component of a system that is performing work, the rope must be in tension (pulled on), not pushed on.  There is a similar saying among engineers:  sh-- doesn't flow uphill.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's doing work or not. The idea is simply that a rope can sustain tension but not compression.

Answer (score 1):

I've been an engineer, and now I am an attorney. I heard an engineer say this recently, and I thought about from both prospectives. As an attorney, I must disagree because there is an assumption that is left out of the saying, if inserted changes the conclusion:

You can't push with the LENGTH of a rope, only its width; and, 
You can't pull with the width of a rope, only its LENGTH.

Think about placing a coil of rope between a stuck vehicle and another vehicle, as a cushion between them.

Comment: You are right, but this is not an answer to the question.