# The prime number $2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is 2 so odd?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15141/why-is-2-so-odd)

I have read few books and articles, almost all of them refer that any prime $p>2$. Just wondering why it has to be $>2$?

Comment: You might want to consider expanding your question and discussing some specific results that you have in mind.  Also, the following is related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/915/is-there-a-high-concept-explanation-for-why-characteristic-2-is-special

Comment: Actually, because it is so *even*

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15141/why-is-2-so-odd is very similar, and was closed as an exact duplicate of the question Sam Nolen linked.

Comment: Reposting a link mentioned in a previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/333728) so that it appears in the "Linked" questions list: [Is there a high-concept explanation for why characteristic 2 is special?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/915)

Answer (score 4):

There are many possible answers to this question, and it depends a lot on the context, but certainly one of the main reasons is that you cannot distinguish between $1$ and $-1$ modulo $2$, whereas $1 \not\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ for any other prime $p$.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean: Why is the prime $2$ "special" (the number theorist's nightmare)? One reason for that is that $2$ is the *smallest* prime.

Answer (score 1):

Because $p-1$ (an expression that appears often dealing with primes) equals 1 **iff** $p=2$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an old saying "All primes are odd, but 2 is the oddest of all!".
For example, if only primes $p > 2$ divide the order of some finite group, by the *Odd Order Theorem* you already know that the group is solvable. If also 2 divides the order, you need more information to draw a conclusion.