# What is the automorphism group of the additive group of the p-adic integers?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Sorry if this is an easy one, I'm a little rusty on my group theory. My first guess was that it's simply the inverse limit of the Aut($\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z})$, with the map when $i\leq j$ given by taking $\sigma\in$ Aut$(\mathbb{Z}/p^j\mathbb{Z})$ to the map $\tilde{\sigma}:\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$ defined by solving $\phi\circ\sigma=\tilde{\sigma}\circ\phi$ where $\phi:\mathbb{Z}/p^j\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$ is the reduction map, but that seems too optimistic - I couldn't think of any reason $\tilde{\sigma}$ would be well-defined, much less be an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$.

Also, barring a full answer to my question, I would be interested in whether Aut$(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is a $p$-group. If not, what can we say about the elements $\sigma\in$ Aut$(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ with order a power of $p$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First the $p$-adic integers are finitely generated (actually cyclic) pro-$p$ group therefore from a result of Serre all automorphisms are continuous. Now as it cyclic it is enough to see what happens to $1$. It has to go to another generator, i.e. any element of the form $a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\cdots$, where $0 \leq a_i < p$ for all $i$ and $a_0 \ne 0$. Hence, every element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is just multiplied by $a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\cdots$. Thus, the automorphism group is the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

It is of course not a pro-$p$ group, but it contains a subgroup of index $p-1$ which is pro-$p$ and is actually again a cyclic pro-$p$ group, i.e. isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and thus have no elements of finite order.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which result of Serre you're referring to, but this is an elementary question so let's be more explicit.  Let $G$ be a profinite group and let $f$ be an automorphism of the underlying abstract group.  Then $f$ is a homeomorphism iff it is continuous iff $f^{-1}$ is continuous iff $f$ maps open subgroups to open subgroups.  Since every group automorphism preserves the index of subgroups and any open subgroup has finite index, a suficient condition for every group automorphism of $G$ to be a homeo is that every finite index subgroup of $G$ is open.  This is the case here...

Comment: Continued: it was rather recently proven that any finitely generated profinite group has the property that every finite index subgroup is open.  I believe this has been known for pro-$p$-groups for a long time: that's probably related to the result of Serre that you're referring to.  

Comment: Indeed, Serre proved that for a finitely generated pro-$p$ group a subgroup of finite index is open. Thus, the topology is determined by the algebra. Hence, every automorphism must be continuous. The questions whether every subgroup of finite index of a finitely generated profinite group is open was known as Serre's problem. It was fairly recently proved to have an affirmative answer by Nik Nikolov and Dan Segal.

Comment: Surely the continuity of group automorphisms is obvious for $\mathbb Z_p$: the subgroups $p^n \mathbb Z_p$ are basic open neighbourhoods of the identity, and they are preserved by group homomorphisms.

Comment: Incidentally: did Serre not publish his result? E.g., in the announcement of their results in CRAS (2003), Nikolov-Segal didn't have any reference to a paper or book of Serre.

Comment: fherzig, yes you are right the case of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is triviel. 

I am not sure what is the origin of Serre's argument, I think it was in some letter, but I have a terrible memory so don't trust me too much. Luis Ribes knows the history of the problem, so if you are interested you can ask him. 

Comment: But isn't $Z_{p}$ uncountable and consequently NOT cyclic? https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/p-adic+integer. Treated as a group,  aren't the units of its associated ring extension precisely the group automorphisms of $Z_{p}$? Please see Andreas Blass's answer below.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_p$ is cyclic in the category of pro-$p$ groups.

Answer (score 6):

Any automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ preserves whether an element is divisible by $p^k$, so it is Lipschitz (in particular, continuous) with respect to the $p$-adic norm.  <strike>On the other hand, any automorphism must preserve $\mathbb{Z}$, which is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.</strike>

What I should've said is that any automorphism is determined by its behavior on $\mathbb{Z}$, hence by its behavior on $1$.  To make up for that mistake, let me offer a sketch of the description of the structure of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\ast}$.  This group clearly splits up as the direct product of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ and the multiplicative group $U = 1 + p \mathbb{Z}_p$.  It is now an interesting exercise to show that the exponential map $x \mapsto u^x, x \in \mathbb{Z}, u \in U$ extends to a map from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $U$ which, given the right choice of $u$, is an isomorphism for $p > 2$.  For $p = 2$, Yiftach Barnea's otherwise excellent answer is slightly wrong and $U$ is in fact isomorphic to $\{ \pm 1 \} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: The part of the answer about preserving Z seems to refer to automorphisms of the *ring* of p-adic integers, whereas the (title of the) question asks about automorphisms of the *additive group*.  It seems to me that multiplication by any unit in Z_p is an automorphism of the additive group, and that these will be the only automorphisms.  

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I always disliked even primes they are just troubles! 

Comment: Speaking of which: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/915/is-there-a-high-concept-explanation-for-why-characteristic-2-is-special