# Is there a deep reason for the fecundity of involutions?

Tags: big-picture

You might have come across [the book of involutions](http://books.google.com/books?id=iNDTyyoaLMIC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) in your travels. A colleague of mine asked whether there is a natural global reason (versus ad-hoc trickery) for considering involutions in mathematics. The above book provides many situations that suggest such a global perspective. Having witnessed the extraordinary power of certain involutions in operator algebras (e.g. in Tomita-Takesaki theory), I'd be interested in hearing about such a global perspective in summary from an expert. I'm aware that this question as I've asked it risks being trite...perhaps warranting the answer "it's the simplest nontrivial symmetry" but the existence of the above book might suggest otherwise:

> **Question:** What are some "global" reasons for considering involutions in mathematics?

Comment: It may be the case that we are way too mathematically primitive to even start making useful use of automorphisms of order three!

Comment: !@Mariano: From where I stand, that is very reasonable!

Comment: I attended an interesting talk given by Tony O'Farrell where he made the case that products of involutions, or more generally, *reversible* elements in groups, occurred very naturally across mathematics. Unfortunately I don't have references to hand but he might have more on his webpage

Comment: Conversely, objects that have absolutely no symmetry are extremely common.   Perhaps the reason why $\mathbb Z_2$ is so striking is that it's just the first non-trivial example of the involution idea, so we're particularly tuned to seeing and making-use of such symmetry.  

Comment: They are often special in arithmetic situations because all the square roots of unity happen to be rational, which is certainly not the case for higher roots of unity.

Comment: Some of the answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/915/is-there-a-high-concept-explanation-for-why-characteristic-2-is-special may be relevant

Answer (score 6):

I don't know the true philosophical reason, but $Z_2$ symmetry is really
omnipresent in Matematics and in the nature. For example, most animals, including practically
all vertebrate animals
(like ourselves) have aproximately $Z_2$ symmetric bodies, and no
larger group. This suggests that $Z_2$ was the favorite group of the Creator, at least in that
period of his activity when we was creating advanced animals:-)

If you prefer Evolution, this $Z_2$ symmetry must somehow be explained by the survival
of the fittest. I don't know exactly how, but this suggests that this is a very important group.
Notice that plants, mushrooms, and simplest animals usually do not have it.

As a result of this (2-fold symmetry of animal bodies) we tend to like this kind of symmetry.
Look at all our technology: cars, ships, airplanes, etc. They all have 2-fold symmetry,
at least from outside (like our bodies, they also have this symmetry only outside).
Once my friend, an airspace engineer, told me that there was a project of an airplane which did not
have this outside 2-fold symmetry. The project was rejected for the only reason that
"no one will want to fly in such an airplane". I am serious:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_wing

In mathematics, from my personal perspective, it is $z\mapsto\overline{z}$ first of all. 
(Once I even proposed
to my co-author to call one of our papers "Some applications of representation theory of $Z_2$");
the paper was full of different representations of this group,
We were working on real algebraic geometry.)

This very same symmetry $z\mapsto\overline{z}$
is also hidden in Hermitian symmetry, $C^*$ algebras, all sorts of "duality" everywhere, etc.
Which suggests that the Creator
of the Universe always had a strong bias in favor of this particular group.

Comment: Many plants (think of flowers and fruit) and simple animals (think of starfish, jellyfish and anemones) exhibit 3-, 5- or 6-fold symmetry, and often higher. Flowers have been "making useful use of automorphisms of order three" for ages. Jellyfish, possibly the most successful animal to ever exist on the planet, have such  striking and high order radial symmetry that they are the biologist's go-to example for demonstrating this phenomenon in nature.

Comment: @Zack: and if you think of ferns, they almost exhibit fractal symmetry!

Comment: Maybe jellyfishy C*-algebras have stars of other orders? 

Comment: I don't like this answer. If we understand well how to use hammers, we are going to notice a lot of nails, but that doesn't mean nails are somehow truly ubiquitous or favoured by the gods, it just means that we recognise them when we see them.

Bonus points to anyone who makes good use of Jellyfish Algebras, btw.

Comment: In this connection, I might add that the word itself, involution, has a botanical origin: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/127332/was-desargues-more-an-euclid-or-an-eudoxos

Comment: Carlo: Thanks! Very interesting detail:-) 

Comment: Ketil: I did not understand your remark: 1) You did not like my answer
because you think it is wrong, or for some other reason?
2) About the hammer: if we "understand well" something, does not this
indicate that this thing EXISTS in the outside world ?

Comment: Alexandre: I suppose the thing I object to is the word "omnipresent". Observing lots of examples of $\mathbb{Z}/2$-symmetry does not mean that it is somehow a fundamental thing, it only means that $\mathbb{Z}/2$-symmetry is a thing we are good at recognising. Most objects (or living things) in nature don't have any symmetry at all, and in a similar way, most objects in mathematics have no symmetry, it's just that we tend to work with those objects that are nice enough that we can do something with them, and having some kind of low-order symmetry is an easy way to be nice.

Answer (score 3):

It all boils down to the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ has two ends!

In all (most) mathematical processes there is some notion of direction: counting, moving (along a curve), mapping from one space **into** another, reading a formula from left to right... the geometry of $\mathbb{R}$ is present always in one way or other, and the flip of the negative and positive ends usually induces some sort of involution.

Comment: An immense number of instances where involutions show up and play a significant role have absolutely nothing to do with the ends of ℝ. I would be awed to see a concrete connection between the Feit-Thompson theorem that simple finite groups have non-trivial involutions (and its central role in the classification of simple groups) and the ends of ℝ, say. 